# How to show username who has login in vb.net hain ms access database

Tags: vb.net

I want to have a registration form, a login window with forgot password option (using security question) and whoever the user login his/her name should be appear on that particular form.

For ex: Form 1 is registration window. Form 2 is login (with password change functionality as per the described criteria) for all users and all users who successfully logedin should be redirected to form3 and their particular names should be appear with Welcome (label). Make sure to use MS Access Database..

I tried to make some logics in my mind but are not successful and on YouTube and even on Google I am unable to get the solution. Please help me!

Comment: When the login form is first displayed, you don't have a valid user logged in and that is when the button to change password is available. I guess you could allow log in, and then put the name of the form and enable a Change Password button along side of a close button they can click to get rid of the form.

Comment: You will have to show some code where you attempted to solve your problem. Then point out a specific programming problem that didn't behave as expected. The criteria is wrong. Only a logged in user should be able to Change a password. Forgot password is a different matter.

Comment: Is this a WinForms desktop, or asp.net? If asp.net, then you could and would use the authentication providers that are built into asp.net, you don't need nor want to roll your own. If desktop then you should state as such, and state the database system you are using, or plan to use (or that you not using any database).